# find the parent of a child in a nested hash

Tags: ruby, json

I have a nested hash as below and I want to find the parent for a specific child using ruby.

For example, I want to find the parent for "field3":123 (12345 being the parent, if my notation is confusing)

```
[
{
  "12345": [
    {
      "entry_id": 543,
      "field1": "value",
      "field2": "other value",
      "field3": 123
    },
    {
      "entry_id": 544,
      "field1": "something",
      "field2": "something else",
      "field3": 456
    }
  ],
  "23456": [
    {
      "entry_id": 545,
      "field1": "new value",
      "field2": "other new value",
      "field3": 789
    },
    {
      "entry_id": 546,
      "field1": "something!",
      "field2": "something else!",
      "field3": 012
    }
  ]
}
]
```

I can iterate over the hash and print the parent I want, but is there a more efficient way of doing it?

I've looked at some other answers and I found this code [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/28652/eliminating-nested-each):

```
def dfs(obj, &blk)
  return enum_for(:dfs, obj) unless blk      
  yield obj if obj.is_a? Hash
  if obj.is_a?(Hash) || obj.is_a?(Array)
    obj.each do |*a|
      dfs(a.last, &blk)
    end
  end
end


def find_node_with_value(obj, key, value)
  dfs(obj).select do |node|
    node[key].respond_to?(:include?) && node[key].include?(value)
  end
end
```

Of course, the above code only helps me find the child nodes. How do I find the parent for the specific child I'm looking for?

Comment: Are the child elements always unique? Could two different parent objects contain a child element with `field3:123`?

Comment: yes, they do. If so, I would like a list of the parents who match that child.

Comment: Adapt the DFS to keep track of the two nodes at once: the parent and the current. Then when the current node is what you want, you'll have the parent.

Comment: Could you give an example of how I could do that?